# PostgreSQL how to group by rows by primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have following query

```
 SELECT "Nomenclature",
            CASE
                WHEN ad."Title" = 'Кухня'
                    THEN au."Value"
                ELSE NULL END AS "Кухня",
            CASE
                WHEN ad."Title" = 'Вегетарианское'
                    THEN au."Value"
                ELSE NULL END AS "Вегетарианское",
            CASE
                WHEN ad."Title" = 'Постное' THEN au."Value"
                ELSE NULL END AS "Постное",
            CASE
                WHEN ad."Title" = 'Постное'
                    THEN au."Value"
                ELSE NULL END AS "Для ресторанов"
     FROM "AttributeUnit" au
              JOIN "AttributeDictionary" ad ON au."AttributeDictionary" = ad."@AttributeDictionary"
     WHERE "Nomenclature" = ANY (ARRAY(SELECT "@Nomenclature" FROM base_info))
       AND ad."Title" IN ('Кухня', 'Вегетарианское', 'Постное', 'Для ресторанов')
```

In the result i have 3 columns with same primary key.
[image]

How to group by the result that it will looks like

| Nomenclature. | Кухня | Вегетерианское | Постное | Для ресторанов |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8677 | Италия | True |  |  |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you want aggregation:

```
SELECT "Nomenclature",
       MAX(CASE WHEN ad."Title" = 'Кухня' THEN au."Value" END) AS "Кухня",
       MAX(CASE WHEN ad."Title" = 'Вегетарианское' THEN au."Value" END) AS "Вегетарианское",
       MAX(CASE WHEN ad."Title" = 'Постное' THEN au."Value" END) AS "Постное",
       MAX(CASE WHEN ad."Title" = 'Постное' THEN au."Value" END) AS "Для ресторанов"
FROM "AttributeUnit" au JOIN
     "AttributeDictionary" ad
     ON au."AttributeDictionary" = ad."@AttributeDictionary"
WHERE "Nomenclature" = ANY (ARRAY(SELECT "@Nomenclature" FROM base_info)) AND
       ad."Title" IN ('Кухня', 'Вегетарианское', 'Постное', 'Для ресторанов')
GROUP BY "Nomenclature";
```